TYPO3 too many redirects
My environment is the following:
Cloudflare (HTTPS) -> AWS ALB (HTTPS) -> AWS EC2 (HTTP) (nginx, php-fpm, typo3)
I am using the Cloudflare Full (strict) SSL mode.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/ssl-modes/full-strict/

So there is double SSL termination, once on Cloudflare and another on the AWS load balancer. The TYPO3 application is receiving requests on HTTP.
The nginx configuration I use is from the official TYPO3 documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/12.4/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html

Excerpt:
...

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location = /typo3 {
    rewrite ^ /typo3/;
}

location /typo3/ {
    absolute_redirect off;
    try_files $uri /typo3/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 240s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 240s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 240s;

    # this is the PHP-FPM upstream - see also: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm
    fastcgi_pass         php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index        index.php;
    include              fastcgi.conf;
}

When I access https://<MY_DOMAIN>.com/typo3/ I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.
My index.php in the typo3/ folder is standard, nothing unusual about it. It should be loading the TYPO3 application.
<?php
call_user_func(static function () {
    $classLoader = require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::run(1, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_BE);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::init($classLoader)->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Http\Application::class)->run();
});

On another TYPO3 website I have, where I don't use Cloudflare + load balancer, where the SSL is terminated on the server itself I don't have this issue.
There is nothing in the logs to indicate where the issue could be. I even enabled debug logging in nginx. TYPO3 receives requests on HTTP. My assumption is that TYPO3 itself is redirecting to HTTPS which causes a redirect loop, but I am not sure.

Related: Where does nginx store the rewrite_log?

To track down the source of the redirects, try to set rewrite_log on; and error_log ...path-to-error.log debug; in the nginx configuration, then open the URL again and analyze the logs. Try replacing the contents of the index.php with something simple such as <?php echo 'hello' to ensure that redirects are not initiated by the PHP code.

@RuslanOsmanov When I change index.php to something simple like <?php echo 'hello' it works fine. But when it's supposed to load TYPO3 it doesn't work. I posted the index.php in the post so you can see it.

I guess, TYPO3 redirects from http to https. There is a ForcedHttpsBackendRedirector middleware which gets activated when the lockSSL configuration option is not false or zero. Try to check if that setting is in effect.

That was it ! I changed 'lockSSL' => false (it was set to 'true' before) in config/system/settings.php and now it works. Thank you so much :)

@RuslanOsmanov you can write it as an answer if you want me to accept it. Otherwise, have a nice day.

There is a ForcedHttpsBackendRedirector middleware in TYPO3 that redirects from http:// to https:// if the lockSSL configuration option is not false or zero. Try to set that option to false in the TYPO3 configuration.
